# How to correct a tax return filed electronically and already approved?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, mistakes, deduction

I know just the basics when it comes to taxes and IRS. So I went to a tax professional to prepare my taxes. He filed my taxes electronically (e-file) and it was approved right there.

I double-checked the documentation before filing and signed it at his office. But when I came back home, I realized he added an expense for gas which is way over what I used last year for gas. I mean, it is an exaggeration - above $3000.00. I work from home, thus I had home-office deductions, and I do not use the car that much for business purposes.

I want to be honest and I want to correct this situation. I am guessing the tax professional made a mistake, but ultimately it is my responsibility to make sure the information is correct and I failed in this.

My question is - how should I correct this mistake? My return was already filed and approved. Appreciate it.

Comment: Clarification: an efiled return is *accepted* within a few hours; that doesn't mean they checked everything, just they didn't find glaring errors like invalid SSN or line 8a doesn't match schedule B. They have 3 years (with some exceptions) to decide if they think any of your figures are wrong and "audit" you (they actually say examine, but everybody else says audit), and you have the same 3 years (also with some exceptions) to amend, although if you delay amending upward it will cost you interest.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - even the IRS calls it an "audit" internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply file an amended return to correct the mistake. This happens all the time and is a standard procedure that every legitimate tax pro can handle. You can work it out with the tax pro about whose mistake it was and who should pay for the additional service.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, if you don't mind. Should I wait for my return before filing an amended return?

Comment: It won't matter from a technical point of view. The amended return will have the new bottom line, whatever it turns out to be. It won't be 'cleaner' one way or the other unless you don't like keeping track of both past and future at the same time in your mind. One thing to keep in mind is that the tax pro will get much busier between now and mid-April. If it were me, I'd take care of it as soon as possible.

Comment: @houstontaxpayer ITYM wait for your *refund*; your (original) *return* is already in. Note that amended returns can't be efiled: you must use paper, which takes IRS longer to process, especially during filing season (i.e. now), so don't worry if you don't hear back for maybe 2-3 months. Use certified mail so you have proof of the filing date.

Comment: Well thank you very much! Yes, I meant _refund_ indeed, thank you.